# Changing label text to what user inputs into UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

This is a very basic question but I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm trying to make a simple "hello world" program where the user inputs what they want into the textfield and whatever they enter goes into the label. However, nothing seems to be happening and I'm unsure why since my push function worked exactly how I expected it to.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var PopUp: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var HelloWorld: UILabel!

    @IBAction func Push(_ sender: UIButton) {
        PopUp.isHidden = false
        PopUp.text = "hello World"
    }

    @IBAction func send(_ sender: UITextField) {
        HelloWorld.text = sender.text
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing you need to know is that method and variable names should start with lowercase letters. Class and struct names start with uppercase letters.

Comment: What event did you connect the `send` action to?

Comment: You should use better naming for your IBOutlet's and IBAction functions, UILabel should be called lblUserEnteredTxt for example, func Push should be btnMyButtonTouchUpInside for example

Comment: you have to connect action with `valueChanged` event.

Comment: @Jaydeep no you do not, the OP either needs to set the HelloWorld.text in the Push func call or he needs to implement UITextFieldDelegate if the OP wants the UILabel to change text as the user types in the UITextField

Comment: i connected the send action to "did end on exit" not too sure if that was the right thing to connect it to haha this is my first time trying to do anything with mobile development

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, `func send` is an unknown to me, as to whether or not it is even firing. `func send` might be called, might not, either way, it is strange to see a `_ sender: UITextField` for an `IBAction`.

What event are you firing related to the `UITextField`? Are you trying to update your `HelloWorld UILabel` as the user types in the `UITextfield`?

To update your `UILabel` with whatever has been typed in your `UITextField`, you just need a `UIButton` Touch Up Inside `IBAction`. I think you can delete `IBAction func send` completely, unless you are trying to update the `UILabel` as the user types in the `UITextField`. Make sure you remove the `IBAction` `Outlet` from your Storyboard if I am correct about this point.

Based on the code you provided the `Push` func does not set text in your `UILabel`. I am assuming `Push` is an `UIButton` Touch Up Inside `IBAction`. You can set your `HelloWorld UILabel` text, in `func Push`, you do not need to use the sender of the event, try this and you will see the `HelloWorld UILabel` text populated:

```
@IBAction func Push(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //PopUp.isHidden = false //why are you doing this? the UITextField PopUp should already be visible if you are typing text into it, so this code is superfluous as the value of PopUp.isHidden is already false
    HelloWorld.text = PopUp.text
    PopUp.text = "hello World"
}
```

If you are trying to have your `UILabel` display the text as you type into the `UITextField` you should clarify your question. And if it is the case you will need to make your `UIViewController` a `UITextFieldDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one way of approach :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    PopUp.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged) // when textfield is edited this will call
}

func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    HelloWorld.text = textField.text
}
```

Comment: Why ignore the `textField` parameter? Why use `if let`? All you need is `HelloWorld.text = textField.text`.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the suggestion and I edited the answer